# Polymer 1.x iron-ajax - how to change on-response programmatically?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like to use one iron-ajax element for several server calls and need to change the on-response parameter, similar to changing the url parameter.  I don't see a way to do this...anyone know how?

Here is my iron-ajax element:

```
<iron-ajax id="xhr" handle-as="json" method="GET">
</iron-ajax>
```

In my code, I'd like to be able to do:

```
this.$.xhr.url = "server.com/getX";
this.$.xhr.onResponse = "handleX";
```

then later:

```
this.$.xhr.url = "server.com/getY";
this.$.xhr.onResponse = "handleY";
```

The above doesn't work and I can't figure out how to do what I want.  I also tried this.$.xhr.onresponse, this.$.xhr.response and a few others but nothing worked.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<iron-ajax>.onResponse` property. The `on-response` attribute is Polymer syntax to register an event handler, and [`response`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#event-response) is an event. To imperatively switch the `response` listener, you'll need to use [Polymer's API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners):

```
Polymer({
  ...
  _switchAjaxListener: function() {
    this.unlisten(this.$.xhr, 'response', '_oldListener');
    this.listen(this.$.xhr, 'response', '_newListener');
  }
);
```

Note the third param is the method name of the event handler (a `string` and not the handler `function` itself).

Comment: thanks tony19!  i casted my vote but apparently i don't have enough reputation to change the displayed value...well!  sorry!